# How to prevent Wire.requestFrom from hanging?

Tags: i2c, wire-library

I'm trying to read data from an Arduino Uno I2C slave via `Wire.requestFrom()` on an Arduino Uno master. The slave's onRequest handler is simply:

```cpp
void I2C_Send()
{

  byte myArray[4];

  myArray[0] = lowByte(acount);
  myArray[1] = highByte(acount);
  myArray[2] = lowByte(bcount);
  myArray[3] = highByte(bcount);

  Wire.write(myArray, 4);

}
```

It seems to work fine for a few iterations, but eventually something happens and the master's `requestFrom()` call hangs indefinitely. What's causing this and how do I prevent it?

I've tried setting various levels of timeout with `Wire.setTimeout(x);` but that has no effect.

Comment: You are using pull-up resistors and connected ground correctly? How long wires? Might have too large capacitive load and need to reduce the I2C clock frequency. Check the signals with a logic analyzer.

Comment: Can you post the master's code?

Comment: Did you find an answer...?